# Trouble Adding Cargo.toml File to Solana Playground

Tags: cargo

I'm currently working on converting my Solidity-based implementation to Rust within the Solana Playground environment. I understand that I need to use a Cargo.toml file to manage dependencies, but I'm encountering issues when trying to add this file.

When I create a Cargo.toml file manually and place it in the src folder, I receive an "invalid file" error. Could someone please guide me on the correct way to use a Cargo.toml file in Solana Playground?

Thank you in advance for your help!
Ferda